# How to show custom error page when returning 403 in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to return a 403 with a custom error page when the request does not contain a header with a certain value. I'm able to return the 403, but it does not use my custom error page. Instead, it uses the nginx default "403 Forbidden" page. How can I get it to use my custom error page?

Here is the relevant portion of my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen 8082;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    error_page 403 /forbidden.html;
    location = /forbidden.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        allow all;
    }

    if ($http_x_azure_fdid != “somevalue”) {
        return 403;
    }

# other stuff here . . . 
}
```

Comment: You probably have a conflict between the `if` and the `error_page`. Can you wrap the `if` in a `location` block?

Comment: @Mike Taverne, Have find any solution for your question ?

Comment: It was so long ago I don't remember!